# Published function on picloud throws an error

Tags: python, rest, google-app-engine, poster

I am trying to send a file to a  function  on picloud via `REST` with poster python library on google app engine (An HTML JPEG image upload). But the function throws this error :

> {"error": {"msg": "Function arguments (POST data) are not valid JSON", "code": 446, "data": "{'parameter': u' filename'}", "retry": false}}

I have set the function's output encoding to `raw`, also I've followed the docs to detail.

Here are some of the function details.

Function name: `detector(name,ifile)`
takes two arguments,an image file and its name

Here is a relevant part of the code:

```
#all needed classes and libraries have been imported,urlfetch, poster,MultipartParam class ect.

#here we go! 
params=[] 
params.append(MultipartParam("Imagename",filename="anyname.jpg",filetype="application/octet-stream",value=some_file_uploaded_via_html_form))
 #http_headers has been defined with appropriate autorization credentials 
datagen,headers=multipart.encode(params) 
data=str().join(datagen)

result=urlfetch.fetch(url=my_defined_function_url,payload=data,method=urlfetch.POST,headers=http_headers)
 print result.content
```

When I add the following lines,in order to include the real function arguments

```
params.append(MultipartParam('name',value=filename_variable) 
params.append(MultipartParam('ifile',value=some_file_uploaded_via_html_form)
```

I get the error

> {"error": {"msg": " charset is defined multiple times", "code": 445, "retry": false}}

I have also tried wrapping the parameters in a dictionary, rather than separate `MultipartParam` instances

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You got a space in your argument:

```
params.append(MultipartParam('ifile',value=some_file_uploaded_via_html _form)
```

This should likely be:

```
params.append(MultipartParam('ifile',value=some_file_uploaded_via_html_form)
```

Note that `some_file_uploaded_via_html_form` is one word.

Comment: Thanks! I have adjusted that,but the problem still remains

Comment: There is a missing _)_ here _value=filename_variable)_ and here _value=some_file_uploaded_via_html_form)_. Check how it looks like in your actual code.

Comment: Here (Yes),but it is normal in the original  code.otherwise it wouldn't run at all: it'll give a syntax error.I feel the code might be semantically wrong,or the  its  screwing up somewhere but I can't just figure out the problem.I've already  posted the part of it that does the real work ,other parts are just if -else statements,html form and library definitions.